# Excel PowerQuery: null values in a number column

Tags: excel, csv, null, powerquery

I am using a PowerQuery query to import data from CSV files. Some cells in the CSV files are empty. When imported into PowerQuery, these cells get an error "Cannot convert the value null to type Number." The field gets (correctly) identified as type=number. However, I'd really just like these error values to just be blank entries, like they were in the original file. "Replace Errors" only allows me to change these error values into numbers (it won't let assign a blank or any non-numeric value). Any ideas on how to get these values to just be blank (or Null)?

Comment: I think this was a bug in Int64.From in a particular version of Power Query. That function definitely works today and will convert both blank values and nulls into null values.

Answer (score 0):

The column has been typed as a whole number Int64 in the "Changed Type" step. Change the type of the column to Decimal number. You should no longer see Errors and your blanks will appear as "null" and will function as nulls.